# Using flowargs from open cti searchAndScreenPop

Tags: lightning, opencti

I am trying to open a flow with preloaded data. In order to do that, I use the OpenCTI searchAndScreenPop with flowargs parameter as follows:

```
sforce.opencti.searchAndScreenPop({
    searchParams: '123465',
    queryParams: '',
    params: {
        FLOW: { 
            flowArgs: [
                {
                    'name': 'phone',
                    'type': 'number',
                    'value': 123456
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    callType: 'inbound',
    callback: function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

The flow only contains a Screen element configured as Start with one phone field.

[image: Flow Screenshot]

The callback is triggered with {"success":true,"returnValue":{},"errors":null}

In the documentation I can see "Specifies arguments to pass to a flow. flowArgs is a list of objects with key-value pairs containing information about the arguments being passed to the flow. Arguments must correspond to input variables of the specified name and type defined in the flow, else they are ignored."

So, my question is: has anyone achieved opening a flow with searchAndScreenPop passing flowArgs? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work you need to specify a variable in the flow in which you will store the value passed via params when calling the searchAndScreenPop function.

1.- Create the variable in the Flow:

[image: Variable phone created as Text data type]

2.- Link the created variable with the field in the Flow:

[image]

3.- Call the Flow with the correct field type:

```
sforce.opencti.searchAndScreenPop({
    searchParams: '123456',
    queryParams: '',
    params: {
        FLOW: {flowArgs: [{'name': 'phone', 'type': 'String', 'value': '123456'}]}
    },
    callType: 'inbound',
    callback: function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Result:

[image]

Take note of the **String** data type when calling the searchAndScreenPop.